# Calculate touch rotation angle with two fingers

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I want to implement a rotation gesture with two fingers in a Unity game.

Therefore I'm saving finger indexes and their initial touch positions once two fingers touch the screen.
Based on these initial positions I want to measure the delta angle of the imagined lines of both finger positions compared to the initial angle.

Are my thoughts correct and how can I implement this if all I have are the touch positions?

Comment: I understand that only one of the fingers would move (the other would remain as the point of the rotation). Draw two (imaginary) lines: from the first finger to the second finger in its initial positions; and from the first finger (not moving) to the final position of the second finger. Determine the angle between both lines (with basic trigonometry).

Comment: This fails if both fingers move at the same time which I would like to encourage the user to do because it feels more natural.

Comment: "Fails"? This cannot fail; it is a suggestion of the kind of movement which your application can account for understanding (if you don't like it suggest a different one). Logically, when I say "not moving", I don't mean not moving even one pixel (but almost not moving). A given movement has to be hardcoded; no angle can be determined between fingers moving randomly. The behaviour which I am describing is more natural (to me, at least) one when trying to rotate. A reference/static/central point is basic in rotation; how would you understand otherwise?

Comment: The reference point would be the middlepoint between the initial touches

Comment: Ah! You mean moving both fingers like they are drawing a circle? OK. It is less natural to me; but would also be fine. The principle is the same: draw the starting/ending lines and calculate the angle between them. In this case, both the starting and end lines can also be drawn by connecting the two points points (= ignore the middle in the calculations).

Comment: (was it me or SO went down?) Or alternatively you might draw all the lines with respect to the middle; you might even assume a global reference completely outside (e.g., bottom/top left)... There are quite a few alternatives; none of them too complicated. Just think carefully about the exact movement you want to account for (+ tolerance -> important issue to avoid relevant miscalculations) and implement the most suitable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first two touch points are A1 and B1, and the second two touch points are A2 and B2, then D1=A1-B1 represents the starting angle and D2=A2-B2 represents the finishing angle, and the change in angle will be something like `atan2(D2.y, D2.x)-atan2(D1.y, D1.x)` (details depend on your implementation). It remains for you to decide if A1 and A2, or A1 and B2 are the same finger! Probably the smaller of the two possibilities is the best choice?